# Как закрыть меню при клике на ссылку?

Tags: javascript

```css
#burger-menu {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 27px;
  width: 27px;
  overflow: visible;
  position: relative;
  z-index: s
}

#burger-menu span,
#burger-menu span:before,
#burger-menu span:after {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 6px;
  width: 33px;
  height: 4px;
  background-color: #d2cecd;
  opacity: 1;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transition: .3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: .3s ease-in-out;
  transition: .3s ease-in-out
}

#burger-menu span:before,
#burger-menu span:after {
  content: ""
}

#burger-menu span {
  right: 0;
  top: 13px;
  z-index: 13;
  width: 33px
}

#burger-menu span:before {
  left: 0;
  top: -10px;
  width: 33px
}

#burger-menu span:after {
  left: 0;
  top: 10px;
  width: 33px
}

#burger-menu.close span {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  top: 33px;
  right: 33px;
  width: 33px;
  position: fixed
}

#burger-menu.close span:before {
  top: 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  width: 33px;
  position: fixed
}

#burger-menu.close span:after {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  opacity: 0;
  width: 0;
  position: fixed
}

#menu {
  z-index: 12;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  height: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 20px;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out
}

#menu.overlay {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)
}

#menu li {
  list-style: none
}

#menu ul {
  padding-left: 0;
  top: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

#menu a {
  color: #fff;
  font-family: "Century Gothic";
  display: block;
  font-size: 32px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  text-decoration: none
}
```

```html
<div id="burger-menu" class="burger">
  <span></span>
</div>
<div id="menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a>1</a></li>
    <li><a>2</a></li>
    <li><a>3</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<script>
  var burgerMenu = document.getElementById('burger-menu');
  var overlay = document.getElementById('menu');
  burgerMenu.addEventListener('click', function() {
    this.classList.toggle("close");
    overlay.classList.toggle("overlay");
  });
</script>
```

Как закрыть меню при клике на ссылку?

Comment: Ну повесь точно такой же слушатель на ссылки

Comment: или проверяй , если клик произошел по ссылке

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var burgerMenu = document.getElementById('burger-menu');
var overlay = document.getElementById('menu');
burgerMenu.addEventListener('click', function() {
  this.classList.toggle("close");
  overlay.classList.toggle("overlay");
});
overlay.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if (e.target.matches('a')) {
    overlay.classList.remove('overlay');
    burgerMenu.classList.remove('close');
  }  
});
```

```css
#burger-menu {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 27px;
  width: 27px;
  overflow: visible;
  position: relative;
  z-index: s
}

#burger-menu span,
#burger-menu span:before,
#burger-menu span:after {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 6px;
  width: 33px;
  height: 4px;
  background-color: #d2cecd;
  opacity: 1;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transition: .3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: .3s ease-in-out;
  transition: .3s ease-in-out
}

#burger-menu span:before,
#burger-menu span:after {
  content: ""
}

#burger-menu span {
  right: 0;
  top: 13px;
  z-index: 13;
  width: 33px
}

#burger-menu span:before {
  left: 0;
  top: -10px;
  width: 33px
}

#burger-menu span:after {
  left: 0;
  top: 10px;
  width: 33px
}

#burger-menu.close span {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  top: 33px;
  right: 33px;
  width: 33px;
  position: fixed
}

#burger-menu.close span:before {
  top: 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  width: 33px;
  position: fixed
}

#burger-menu.close span:after {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  opacity: 0;
  width: 0;
  position: fixed
}

#menu {
  z-index: 12;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  height: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 20px;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out
}

#menu.overlay {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)
}

#menu li {
  list-style: none
}

#menu ul {
  padding-left: 0;
  top: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

#menu a {
  color: #fff;
  font-family: "Century Gothic";
  display: block;
  font-size: 32px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  text-decoration: none
}
```

```html
<div id="burger-menu" class="burger">
  <span></span>
</div>
<div id="menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a>1</a></li>
    <li><a>2</a></li>
    <li><a>3</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Нужно поставить обработчик на весь блок с меню и если клик именно на ссылке, то делать тоже самое, что и кнопка закрытия

```js
  var burgerMenu = document.getElementById('burger-menu');
  var overlay = document.getElementById('menu');
  function close() {
 burgerMenu.classList.toggle("close");
    overlay.classList.toggle("overlay");
  }
  burgerMenu.addEventListener('click', close);
  
  overlay.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
 if(event.target.tagName === "A") close();
  })
```

```css
#burger-menu {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 27px;
  width: 27px;
  overflow: visible;
  position: relative;
  z-index: s
}

#burger-menu span,
#burger-menu span:before,
#burger-menu span:after {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 6px;
  width: 33px;
  height: 4px;
  background-color: #d2cecd;
  opacity: 1;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transition: .3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: .3s ease-in-out;
  transition: .3s ease-in-out
}

#burger-menu span:before,
#burger-menu span:after {
  content: ""
}

#burger-menu span {
  right: 0;
  top: 13px;
  z-index: 13;
  width: 33px
}

#burger-menu span:before {
  left: 0;
  top: -10px;
  width: 33px
}

#burger-menu span:after {
  left: 0;
  top: 10px;
  width: 33px
}

#burger-menu.close span {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  top: 33px;
  right: 33px;
  width: 33px;
  position: fixed
}

#burger-menu.close span:before {
  top: 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  width: 33px;
  position: fixed
}

#burger-menu.close span:after {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  opacity: 0;
  width: 0;
  position: fixed
}

#menu {
  z-index: 12;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  height: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 20px;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out
}

#menu.overlay {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)
}

#menu li {
  list-style: none
}

#menu ul {
  padding-left: 0;
  top: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

#menu a {
  color: #fff;
  font-family: "Century Gothic";
  display: block;
  font-size: 32px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  text-decoration: none
}
```

```html
<div id="burger-menu" class="burger">
  <span></span>
</div>
<div id="menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a>1</a></li>
    <li><a>2</a></li>
    <li><a>3</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```